# Can a particle have an imaginary mass?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, mass, tachyon

Now, I'm not very involved in the physical sciences, beyond some high-school classes - though I did listen to some college lectures for physics.

I was reading ["Do Tachyons Exist?" by John Baez](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/ParticleAndNuclear/tachyons.html), which is a bit advanced for some people. However, the author makes one claim I find questionable: that we can have an imaginary mass. If we take the mass to be imaginary, then Einstein's mass-momentum relationship remains intact.

Comment: The author doesn't actually claim that we "can have" imaginary mass, only that imaginary mass is what comes out of the equation "if" Tachyons exist,   "If it exists, then this could happen" is a pretty broad liberty to take.  I don't mean to trash the article either, cause it's a valid proposal to inquire about, but it's more accurate to say imaginary mass "might" exist and many things "might" exist that haven't been discovered yet.   Imaginary time might exist too (inside black holes)  :-)

Comment: If you ever learn about tachyon condensation, make sure not to get confused about what makes it "tachyonic".

Answer (score 8):

Mathematically, yes. Physically, no. Tachyons are a sign of an unstable theory and need to be dealt with. tachyons are these weird particles which move faster than the speed of light. Special relativity tells us that mass tends to infinity as an object's velocity tends towards light speed i.e. $$m = \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}},$$ which as $v\rightarrow c, m \rightarrow \infty.$ But if $v^2 > c^2, \ m \sim -i m_0.$ When you plug this into the energy mass condition, $E = \sqrt{m^2 c^4 + p^2 c^2}$, you get negative energies. (This is the sign of an instability. In fact, in Minkowski spacetime, this is not allowed.) What this means is that as the ratio $v^2/c^2 > 0$ increases, the faster it goes, the more mass this particle loses. In theory this is unbounded from below, and if there is no mechanism to prevent this particle from existing, your theory will be plagued with problems such as the existence of particles with $m^2 = -\infty.$ So tachyons are not a sign of a healthy theory. In fact, this is also why bosonic string theory is plagued with problems - the vacuum state is tachyonic and one needs to fix the number of dimensions to 26 in order for this tachyon to be removed the theory. (that's not exactly the reason why you fix d = 26 in the bosonic string theory but it also seems to deal with the tachyon problem.)

But otherwise, the tachyon is very interesting from the perspective of causality as well. Particles are causal if they travel within the light cone. Tachyons do not travel inside the light cone so what this means is that $ds^2 = +1$ for the tachyon which means that it is a spacelike quantity and can travel backwards in time. (Hence, if you go faster than the speed of light, you go backwards in time!)

Comment: _"Hence, if you go faster than the speed of light, you go backwards in time"_ : only if c is the max speed while the relevance of tachyons assumes the contrary

Comment: I don't follow your point entirely, but allowing tachyons to exist implies a break in the causal structure of the theory. But since nothing can go faster than the speed of light, causality is safe.

Comment: indeed, in case of ( exotic objects ) speed FTL , the theory must be splitted in light mechanics and tachionics mechanics :) causality must always be safe ; saying that FTL implies going backward in time is just the last part of a _Reductio ad absurdum_

Comment: No, what I mean to say is that objects with spacelike norms can form closed time curves which violate causality. But your claim of splitting physics into "light mechanics and tachyonic mechanics" is not quite right. The point is that IF you have tachyonic modes, then it is a sign of a serious pathology in the theory which manifests in things like unbounded negative mass, causality violation and things like null and negative norm states in a field theory. Therefore, tachyons are to be prohibited in a theory.

Comment: you cannot assume in the same theory opposed assumptions. If speed FTL is postulated, the theory must be cleaned of all the consequences of having a speed c finite and known. In example, usual metrics must be rewriten or else the concept must evolve. But, it's just a syntaxic discussion :) good answer

Comment: You still keep c, it would just costs you an infinite amount of energy to decelerate a tachyon down to c, like it would cost you an infinite amount of energy to accelerate a particle up to c. But c stays c, with tachyons or without.

Comment: @СимонТыран : c stays for the light and known forms of energy. For other objects, a new theory may assume what it wants before the experiments

Comment: So, as I understand, you're saying Einstein's special theory is unstable for the very reason that you can plug a v > c into the formula for m & get an imaginary number that then produces a negative E. In that case, why can't we stabilize the theory by restricting the formula to all v <= c?

Comment: You get infinities in speed, so what... stop renormalizing elsewhere to compensate... ;-)

Comment: @user106422 ummm just so you know allowing tachyons to exist does no break Causality, Einstein said that items with mass cannot travel faster than light, but we have the concepts of negative mass and even imaginary mass it is another matter all together, Also I still to this day do not understand what negative mass and imaginary mass objects look like... :(

Answer (score 2):

Virtual particles can have imaginary mass, so to the extent that virtual particles are real (as opposed to being just a term in a perturbation series): Yes.

Consider electron scattering off nucleons in the lab frame: A beam with energy $E$ scatters by $\theta$ degrees, with a final energy of $E'$ is mediated by the exchange of a virtual photon with squared four momentum (for $E>>m$):

$$ Q^2 = EE'\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}} > 0 $$

which corresponds to an imaginary mass. This is just the kinematics of taking 2 ultra-relativistic electron four momenta and subtracting them (the so-called $t$ channel):

$$ q_{\mu} = k_{\mu} - k'_{\mu}$$

It is tachyon-like in the sense that the end points of the exchange are space-like. You often hear: "the electron emits a virtual photon which is then absorbed by the proton". That statement leaves out "the proton (Parton) emits a virtual photon that is absorbed by the electron".

In the old Time-ordered perturbation theory, one needed to address each process separately. The manifestly covariant Feynman diagram includes both, hence one just says "they exchange a virtual photon".

Comment: Can you take a picture of the virtual Particle and send it to me?? I'm really curious what a particle with imaginary mass looks like, please dont send me an imaginary particle....

Answer (score -2):

OK so if the math gives, why not reinterpret what negative Values for E mean? Space-Time contracts near high energies, but is flat overall, so it must expand as well. I'm not saying Tachyons are the Dark Matter we're looking for, unless that's exactly the case, and negative values for E could be interpreted in that manner. Near a concentration of negative energy, time would speed up, making every particle seem to move faster to an outside observer, and it would push matter away from its center, and forcing light to take a longer path, redshifting it. If these hypothetical imaginary mass particles existed, and they were faster than light, this would make it hard for them to concentrate in one region. BUT they themselves would also be repelled by positive energy concentrations, which have traditional mass, and they would rebound around in the megastructures of the cosmos, the matter herding them in but being pushed away by them at the same time, until the megastructures of the cosmos became so weak that they couldn't serve as a barrier anymore, and Spacetime then expands so fast that Milkdromeda can't see anyone else out there anymore. There wouldn't be any Big Rip, however, because the negative energy would still be held at bay by the matter concentration.

There needn't be a causality paradox here, either. The hypothetical imaginary mass particles themselves would only 'interact' with the curvature of spacetime, not with eachother, nor with "regular" matter. They also wouldn't concentrate into white holes, the mathematical anti-black-holes, because there's no force sticking them together; the mass/density needed to herd together enough negative energy to create a white hole would be a black hole of at least counterequal Energy(super hypothetically). No force in the universe could do that because it would be like accelerating the black hole to light speed to get it close enough to the negative energy.

Of course, all of that makes it pretty much impossible to prove - or disprove- anything I've claimed about these hypothetical particles. So, they're not even hypothetical, but purely... imaginary

*Crickets*

Comment: I meant to write Dark Energy. Dark Matter certainly doesn't fit these criteria... at all

Comment: Hi Nicolai Veliki: Welcome to Phys.SE. You can edit your answer to what you meant to write.

Comment: "Of course, all of that makes it pretty much impossible to prove - or disprove- anything I've claimed about these hypothetical particles. So, they're not even hypothetical, but purely... imaginary" Unless we can go backwards in time lol.... We have time dilation, maybe if we have time reversal we will find tachyons...